# Avoid having to re-type password to access keychain item from macOS command line app after every re-compilation?

Tags: macos, code-signing, keychain, code-signing-certificate, darwin

I'm building a macOS command line app that stores tokens in Keychain as `kSecClassGenericPassword`. I'm using a self-signed certificate to codesign the app for local development. (I am not adding any entitlements.)

The problem is what whenever I re-compile (and re-sign) the binary, I get a prompt for my admin password whenever the binary accesses the keychain item. According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290058/how-does-macos-keychain-acl-determine-which-apps-have-access), keychain should detect that both versions of the binary are signed and have the same identifier, and not ask for my password. Is there anything I'm missing or any workaround to avoid having to enter my password so frequently?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but I strongly suspect the issue is that your certificate is *self-signed*. Most security decisions in macOS are based on the *team identifier* embedded in the signing certificate. This prevents a malicious program from stealing credentials from another application simply by giving itself the same bundle identifier and being signed. For the authorisation check to be skipped, both the bundle identifier *and the team identifier* must match.

I suspect that even if you did somehow embed a team ID in your certificate, because the certificate is not in turn signed/issued by Apple, the team ID would (rightly) not be considered reliable by the OS, so your binary is treated as effectively unsigned. I suspect the CDHash (cryptographic hash of the binary code) is used for authorisation instead, and your certificate is ignored.

I don't know your reasons for using a self-signed certificate, but as far as I'm aware you can get a very basic Apple Developer certificate from Apple for free, and using this to sign your binary should suffice for solving the issue you are encountering, as the free certificate includes a Team ID.

The only other workaround I can think of is to use a helper process with the sole purpose of storing and retrieving the credentials, and using XPC to communicate with this from your main binary. The helper process would hopefully not need to be updated as frequently as the main program, so you'd rarely see the authorisation prompt. This is of course still rather awkward, and now you need to secure the XPC service against malicious clients yourself.