Can I avoid setting system permissions after every recompile?
In particular I am using the C++ library SFML on MacOS 10.14.2, and the method that requires system permission is sf::Mouse::setPosition. Alas, every time I make any tweak to the code and make a fresh build, the OS doesn't recognize the new build as having permission any more, and will not perform the mouse jump called for by the code unless I go back to Settings and reregister my game application. This is quite a hindrance to trying to develop a game idea requiring the fiat setting of the mouse/cursor position.
Is there any way to guarantee permission for each new build? Or any other way to work around this?

This is a MacOS question more so than a C++ or SFML question. I added the tag, but left the others for now.

That sucks man. I would rather use Linux for development purposes. Even Windows is better.

There are plenty of guides online about installing SFML on MacOS - most seem to assume the user doing the installation has required privileges. Generally speaking, if the library is rebuilt and (permissions permitting) copied to relevant locations by an unprivileged user, it will lose any previously installed privileges that user does not have.   Your options will either be to login as a privileged user to re-install the library, or (possibly simpler) execute the complete build/reinstall process as a privileged user.

Some breadcrumbs: macOS has required permissions for this since 10.14 and a SO question about it. No solution that I can see, though. There are also two SFML issues

@Botje , thanks for the research. I don't see a solution either. Peter , I'm using the computer as admin and I don't see anywhere to grant myself more "privileges" than I already have... it isn't SFML itself that's requiring permission, but rather individual created applications that utilize a mouse-setting method.

I was told on another forum that permissions would (probably?) be persistent if I used code signing. I don't know much about that, though, and it sounds like you have to have an annual subscription or something?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58291165/233944

Thank you for the link... I asked another SO question because currently I can't get XCode to let me use a self-signed certificate...

I found a way to resolve this issue.
In Xcode menu choose Settings. In Settings choose Accounts tab. If you haven't added your Apple ID to the list, click the "+" and do so. You should now have a "team" that looks like `My Name (Personal Team). Then go to the "Signing and Capabilities" tab (which appears in the tab set along with "Build Settings" and "Build Phases" etc.) Now make sure that "Team" is set to "My Name (Personal Team)", make sure your bundle identifier is filled out uniquely, and make sure that "Signing Certificate" is set to "Developer", and not "Run Locally".
